# Looking for a Java equivalent to .NET's Snippet Compiler

Tags: java, .net, compiler-construction, code-snippets

I am looking for a Java equivalent to .NET's Snippet Compiler. Is there any such utility out there? That or a really light weight Java IDE for Windows? Eclipse and NetBeans seem too heavy-weight to practice basic syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lightest is notepad + javac.

But, Eclipse has a snippet compiler.  And the size has a reason, it is a very powerful tool.

Comment: It would help to mention where in Eclipse it is and how to use it.

Comment: try as I might I cannot find it in Eclipse. You mean scrapbook pages?

Comment: Compile and Execute Java, C#, and PHP From Your Favorite Text Editors - https://dzone.com/articles/compile-and-execute-java-c-and-php-from-your-favou